# How to call this method?

Tags: c#

i'm just a newbie in programming and i made a function, just one stupid problem and a very stupid question.Please don't rude, How do i call this function from a different form or class. or even in the same form

```
public void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
            for (int i = 0; i <= dtInfo.Rows.Count - 2;i++ )
            {
                Battery = Convert.ToDateTime(dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
                Oil = Convert.ToDateTime(dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString());
                Fran = Convert.ToDateTime(dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString());
                lastkm = int.Parse(dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value.ToString());

            batt = Battery - DateTime.Now;
            doil = Oil - DateTime.Now;
            dfran = Fran - DateTime.Now;

            if (batt.Days <= 7)
            {
               dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

            }
            if (doil.Days <= 7)
            {
                dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[14].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            if (dfran.Days <= 7)
            {
                dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[12].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;

            }
            if (lastkm <= 500)
            {
                dtInfo.Rows[i].Cells[13].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }



        }
    }
```

EDITED

[image: first open form]
when i first open my form the color change then when i reopen it
[image: reopened form]
it wont change  but when i trace the code the value of the color was change but not the color in the cell

Comment: FYI, your question does not require that you post the entire method - only the signature (`public void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)`)

Answer (score 4):

That's an event handler, and you can't raise the event yourself unless:

1. The class exposes a protected (or even public) method to fire it directly, but that doesn't happen usually in the .NET classes.
2. You trigger it by doing what the actual event represents -- In your case, when the databinding between your grid and your source is complete.

You can call that method, though, but it wouldn't have any relevant meaning, since you wouldn't raise the event. Still, if the event logic doesn't matter and you just want that code to execute, you can do it through:

```
dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(null, null);
```

But in that case, you can just wrap that method's content in a simple method with a returning type of `void` and no parameters.

Comment: actually im trying to change the color of a cell in a datagridview. Before i use the public void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{ function.... the datagridview cell change it colors...but when i close it and re.open it again the color wont change anymore...

Comment: @user974015 What do you mean by "close it and re-open it"? Do you add the handler to your event?

Comment: like...when i close the form...then re-open it... the datagridview cells wont change color anymore...but when i tried to trace it...the cell gets the value of the backcolor but it wont apply...in visual datagrid

Comment: @user974015 I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your problem. If you want to programmatically re-color the grid (as long as you know when it needs to be done, you can just put your drawing code in another method and call it.

Comment: @eve... i've edited my post...can you please check it out.. thanks... :D

Comment: @user974015 What code executes when you click on the "Exit" button?

Comment: `datagrid.DataSource = null;                 
  datagrid.Rows.Clear();
  datagrid.Columns.Clear();
this.close();` @eve

Comment: @user974015 Then, how do you re-open the form again? I believe that you don't subscribe to the event again, when you open the form.

Comment: @ eve well when i called it..its the same process when i opened it for the 1st time....  i made a very long function that will get the data..to a datatable... and i was a success...in putting the data on the datagrid..(as you can see on the 2nd image).... only the color didnt change at all...

Comment: @user974015 I'm sorry but the information about your problem that I have is limited. Try to subscribe to the event from the constructor of your form, or from some other method that you will be SURE to be called when you re-open your form.

Comment: when i open the form.. i use the `form.ShowDialog()` @eve

Comment: @user974015 Try `form.Show()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete() is just a plain old method

```
dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(this, new RoutedEventArs());
```

Should do the trick if you want to call it from the same object.

if you want to reuse that section of code I would take everything within the method and create a separate public method so you can call it from other places and from other objects.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where the function is located. If you have it under the same class as your form, you can just call it in the same scope. But from what I see, this is a event handler, and you shouldn't need to call it, as it handles the dataGridView event "DataBindingComplete". For more info about it, visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx).

However if you need to call it for some reason you can just do:

```
dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(null, null)
```